# Syntax issue in creating subsets based on column contents pandas

Tags: python, pandas, syntax, syntax-error

My dataset looks as follows:

| Country code | Value |
| --- | --- |
| IRL | 10 |
| IRL | 12 |
| IRL | 11 |
| FRA | 15 |
| FRA | 16 |
| IND | 9 |
| IND | 11 |
| USA | 19 |
| USA | 4 |
| HUN | 30 |
| HUN | 1 |
| HUN | 31 |
| HUN | 11 |

I am attempting to extract rows with specific country codes using the `.loc` function, however this doesn't seem to work when multiple strings are added into the function.

My code looks as follows:
`subset = df.loc[df["Country Code"] == ("IRL", "FRA", "IND")]`

When I do this, my code doesn't return an error, but rather gives me an empty subset, so I am curious, what is wrong with my syntax, and what is my current code actually doing?

Answer (score 0):

`df["Country Code"] == ("IRL", "FRA", "IND")` checks for equality between the tuple `("IRL", "FRA", "IND")` and each item in the column `Country Code` - which is why it doesn't error out and would give you nothing (as none of the values in your column is a tuple).

you want to use `pd.Series.isin` i.e. `df["Country Code"].isin(("IRL", "FRA", "IND"))` instead

Comment: That explanation of why it doesn't work makes perfect sense, idk how I didn't think of it thank you! For the pd.series.isin, I will only be getting a True/False output rather than the ability to create a subset containing the rows with these country codes no?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear - the `df["Country Code"] == ("IRL", "FRA", "IND")` in your code would be replaced with `df["Country Code"].isin(("IRL", "FRA", "IND"))`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by nested by multiple loc

```
display(df.loc[df["Country Code"] =="IRL" || df.loc[df["Country Code"] =="FRA", [columns] )
```

and so on